# What is the best free XLIFF editor?

Tags: flash, localization, internationalization, xliff

I'm localizing my Flash application.
Flash keeps localization data in XLIFF format, this is an XML dialect.

Several users from different countries want to help me with translation.
But it's hard for regular people to edit XML files.
I'm looking for a free editor, since I don't want to buy the editor for each user.

Which free XLIFF editor would you recommend?

Comment: I've just purchased a 30 € edition of "[PoEdit](https://poedit.net)" for Windows. Seems to me on of the better tools for Windows. They also have a free version available.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So far I've found [Transolution](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eviltrans/) and there are a few more listed on the [XLIFF Tools](http://web.archive.org/web/20120430210001/http://xliff-tools.freedesktop.org/wiki/Resources) page.

Transolution seems to be supported on Windows and it uses Python. I don't know what OS solution you're looking for, but it there is hope on the XLIFF Tools Software list.

Interesting question, I'd like to see what is the best free XLIFF editor.

Comment: Horrific state of affairs in XLIFF community. I can't even..

Comment: You commented 3 hours ago. And this post was from 2009. So now I am still unsure of what to use. Why did you say "horrific state"?

Comment: @coderama yeah I guess it's really out of date answer and question, both should be buried. I came here from google btw. I say horrific because it is horrific, what's hard to understand? It's 2015 here ya.

Comment: Even if you check tools newer then 2009 and not mentioned here the situation is still awful. And if you want to get to all this cheap translators out there (as i do for my project) it gets worse. I'm writing my own toolset now.

Comment: Mid 2017 and I came here desperately searching for good XLIFF editors.. looks like it's still horrible..

Comment: XLIFF Tools link is broken

Comment: @jimver04 thanks for the heads-up, just updated the link :)

Comment: anybody tried this? https://poeditor.com/kb/xliff-editor

Comment: Don't know about "best", but I added XLIFF support to [Poedit](https://poedit.net) ([GitHub](https://github.com/vslavik/poedit), formerly gettext-only translations editor) last year.

Comment: It's 2020 and the state is still awful. Today I spent about 4 hours trying every tool I could find that was free. NONE of the tools would work with the Salesforce export to the point where they didn't require hand-editing afterward. I gave up and went back to STF which is a glorified tab-delimited file that I can (carefully) import into Excel and back. It breaks on any field that has a comma or special character in the Key; so those have to be hand-removed, but at least my biz analysts understand Excel.

Comment: *Addendum: the state is awful if you're coming here because you're trying to export XLIFF from Salesforce, edit it, and reimport it. I can't judge the state of the tools for other purposes.Could this just be Salesforce's fault? Maybe, but it is going to be a very common use case for a lot of people hitting this question.

Comment: @CarlBussema I haven't look at the topic in a few good years and I wish my answer wasn't at the top but a better working solution. FWIW here are few more to evaluate: [Qt Linguist](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtlinguist-index.html), [Brightec editor](https://xliff.brightec.co.uk/), [OmegaT](https://omegat.org/), [Virtaal](http://virtaal.translatehouse.org/), [KDE Localize](https://userbase.kde.org/Lokalize), [XLIFF Translator](http://felix-cat.com/tools/xliff-translator/)

Comment: @CarlBussema Angular uses XLIFF for translation

Comment: I tried the various options listed above. Only [Poedit](https://poedit.net/) worked well with Angular xliffs. Unfortunately, it is missing an option to update the translated file when new translation units are added/updated.
As a simple, but effective alternative, I found [XLIFF Translator Tool](https://github.com/DavidOndrus/xliff-translator-tool/releases), which also allows merging.

Comment: On 2021, I'm using WebTranslateIt which works like a charm ... but unfortunatly, is is free only if you have less than 500 key (which is not my case anymore, and that is why I search for another tool)

Answer (score 4):

Transolution works great on a PC, but it crashes sometimes and our translators have to save often.

On the Mac, if you don't have Snow Leopard, LocFactory Editor is a nice option, but not upgrading to Snow Leopard wasn't an option, so we've stopped using it.

We're currently using [Open Language Tools](https://open-language-tools.java.net/), which works great on Linux and a Mac and recommend it to all our translators. It also has some nice XLIFF validation.

Comment: It seems, that this project is dead? I can't download anything from there.

Comment: Huh yeah that's strange. They appear to be available here now: http://java.net/downloads/open-language-tools/snapshots/

Comment: That's Oracle's evildoing for sure ;)))

Comment: None of these links are valid anymore...