# Can't find a working free xliff editor for OSX Lion

Tags: translation, osx-lion, xliff, typo3-flow

## Attempts

I tried:

- **Virtaal**
- **PoEdit** (not xliff but convertible)
- **Open Language Tools TransEditor**
- **LocFactory Editor**

And I think I'm getting nuts.

### Virtaal

With **Virtaal** it seems I can't create files (or am I to stupid ?). Also when I open the tutorial `.po` and try to save that, **Virtaal** crashes.

### PoEdit

With **PoEdit** I can create a new project but on finishing he throws me an error:

> Poedit did not find any files in scanned directories.
>   Entries in the catalog are probably incorrect.
>   Updating the catalog failed. Click on 'More>>' for details.

### Open Language Tools TransEditor

And in **Open Language Tools TransEditor** I created a new project but I can't create any new lines/translations.

### LocFactory Editor

I also tried **LocFactory Editor**. When I launch it I get

> No document could be created

And in the menus I also can't find anything like **New File** or so.

---

## Question

So what is that ? Am I to dumb to create `xliff` files using an `xliff` editor ? should I google for `xliff` creator or what ?

### Requirements

- I want to have `xliff` files for a **FLOW3** project.
- I'd like to use an editor that **supports plural forms**.
- Support for Mac OS X

Comment: Potentially related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770077/what-is-the-best-free-xliff-editor

Answer (score 7):

Hi you can try this one
[XLIFFTool](https://itunes.apple.com/lv/app/xlifftool/id1074282695?mt=12)

Comment: the UI could be improved, but it's free and works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [OmegaT](http://www.omegat.org/).

It's not just for XLIFF, but it should work reasonably well with XLIFF documents.
Make sure the  elements have a copy of the text to translate before opening the file in OmegaT. You can also use Rainbow to create an OmegaT project with XLIFF files: it will add the copy of the source text for you.

Hope this helps,
-ys

Answer (score 0):

There is free XLIFF online editor at [Brightec](http://xliff.brightec.co.uk). Not sure about plural forms support.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [poedit](https://poedit.net) tool for that.